# What should I do if I don't know the length of array beforehand?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my java code:

```
class soduku
{
    int[][] board ={
         {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         {0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         {0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 0},
         {0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 7, 0, 0},
         {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
         {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8},
         {0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         {0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0}};
    int[][] mutable = mutable();
    int[][] mutable()
    {
        int i,j;
        int count = 0;
        for(i=0;i<board.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<board[i].length;j++)
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            count++;
        }
        int [][] mutable = new int[count][2];
        int k = 0;
        for(i=0;i<board.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<board[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(board[i][j]==0)
                {
                    mutable[k][0]=i;
                    mutable[k][1]=j;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        return mutable;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have to count the number of zeroes so that I can declare the array mutable.
I want to know if there's a better way so that could do the same thing. I am new to Java and only know about arrays and some basic data type.

Comment: Use a list, or create an array big enough to hold the maximum number of values.

Comment: Answer: use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @khelwood "This question has already answers here" you listed are too old. You can use `Stream` to create an array of unknown size in advance.

Comment: @saka1029 You can add a new answer to that question if you think it is worthwhile.